# Can you put the git log log regex matching group in the git pretty output?

Tags: git

Suppose I have the following query:

```
git log -100 -i --grep="^\[.*JIRA.*\]"
```

This assumes a git comment something like

```
"[JIRA1234] Adding the graph to the customer balance page"
```

Then I want to format the output to show just that matching group eg `[JIRA1234]`.

Now I think I should be able to do this with:

```
git log -100 -i --grep="^\[.*JIRA.*\]" --pretty="%1"
```

But that doesn't work.

Another way to do it is by piping into grep

```
git log -100 -i --grep="^\[.*JIRA.*\]" --pretty=oneline | grep -o '\[.*JIRA.*'
```

But then you lose the ability to add author names and other tricks with the `git log --pretty` output.

My question is: **Can you put the git log log regex matching group in the git pretty output?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find any direct approach to this request. If the pattern `"^\[.*JIRA.*\]"` occurs only once in the commit log message, this command can help:

```
git log -100 -i --grep="^\[.*JIRA.*\]" --pretty=%H | while read line
do 
  p=$(git log -1 $line --pretty=%B | grep -i -o -e "^\[.*JIRA.*\]")
  git log -1 $line --pretty="$p %h %an %cn foo bar"
done
```

If the patter occurs multiple times, some extra commands are needed, like `head -1` or another `while` loop.

Comment: Dumb question - if you're piping it into grep, why do you need the git log twice? Why can't you just use it once like in the question example with the piped grep?

Comment: @hawkeye In the while loop, the first git log to to get the string matching the pattern and the second to get the format log. `--pretty=oneline` ignores the body of the commit log message but shows only the subject. Besides, your example may match more than the pattern.

Comment: Any time your `--pretty` format is just `%H`, you might as well use `git rev-list` directly (`git log` and `git rev-list` take the same options, as they're almost just one command in terms of source code). (I also prefer `--no-walk` to `-1` these days although that's actually longer to spell out :-) and the performance is basically the same.)

Comment: @torek thanks for your advice. I just prefer porcelain commands if possible since they are more friendly to any git user.